# What would be observable about a hypervelocity killer asteroid?

Tags: space, space-warfare

An early warning scout ship sits in deep space, making various kinds of observations and doing deep space science experiments, when suddenly a 2-kilometre-wide asteroid zooms past at about 0.9c on its way to ruin someone’s day. It takes all the observations it can as it passes and forwards them to home base to take action.

The scout has a comprehensive suite of instruments that allow it to observe the asteroid via all currently-known (as of ~2022) active and passive methods*. It lacks any science-fictional/magical sensors applicable to the task.

The asteroid can be assumed to pass the scout at a distance of approximately 1,000km, or the minimum distance that the scout would not affect the asteroid in the course of its observations. Assume that the scout can survive the experience. (If simpler, it can be treated as an abstract point directly intersected by the asteroid.)

What would the scout be able to observe and report back about the asteroid?

Actually stopping or deflecting the asteroid is not in scope here - assume appropriate countermeasures are implemented with scifi tech.

*Literature review suggests that at minimum the asteroid should be pingable with a radar (or other -dar), and at the requisite velocities might be able to be picked up on infrared and possibly visual from the impact of space dust creating heat.

Comment: You have a scout ship, which humanity can't achieve with today's tech. That means you're already invoking "science-fictional/magical" technology. To get reasonable answers you'll need to explain what sensors are actually on the ship—because as-written, any answer between and including "not a darn thing" and "UHR photographs, wide-spectrum spectroscopy, gravity, thermal of the leading shockwave, radiography and short-wavelength emissions, and an FM broadcast repeating the phrase 'Better Luck This Time Truman!'" are all valid.

Comment: BTW, "currently" can mean in terms of the scout ship's timeline or ours. If you intended the "comprehensive suite of instruments" to be limited by 2022 technology, you need to say that. If that's the case, what has research into current instrumentation (e.g. [this](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/instruments/)) not taught you that requires our input?

Comment: @JBH I’m not equipped to enumerate a useful list of current technology - research and general knowledge does suggest to me that, for example, an active radar should be able to produce a valid result if it’s active at the time. Similarly, I imagine an infrared or possibly visible light telescope should allow identification at least as it passes, as I _think_ the impact of space dust would make it visible from heating effects. But I’m not confident enough to enumerate this as a constraint on the question

Comment: Fair enough, but we still need a clarification of either the year reference for limiting the analyzed tech or the list of equipment on the ship. You're going to run into "frame rate" problems (to use a term familiar to most all of us today). Radar has a limited sweep speed. Video is not continuous. If the instruments are pointing at an oncoming object, they have a good chance. If it's passing by with a lateral scan, they'll likely not detect anything. And dust impacting at a "massive fraction of the speed of light" will likely tear the scout ship apart. But, give us a limit and we can proceed.

Comment: And in addition to what JBH said, please specify the "massive" fraction of a speed of light. Is that 1%, 10%, 90%, 99%, 99.9999%, or what? How close does the asteroid pass past the observation point? 1 km, 10 km, 1000 km, 100,000 km?

Comment: @AlexP I’ll edit to detail it into the question itself, but my intent runs along the lines of: Velocity at limit approaching c, point of closest pass at limit approaching 0m, but ruling out trivialising results like ‘Asteroid collides with observer and destroys it instantly, no results are obtained’. Would I be better off rephrasing down to a spherical cow representation with a light-speed rock intersecting an insubstantial observer?

Comment: I am obliged to point out that a 2km asteroid travelling at something asymptotically approaching light speed is not a planet killer, it's a solar system killer.  (Also, if it's reaaaallly close to c, its relativistic mass is going to be enormous.)

Comment: Maybe this idea helps to narrow down the speed somewhat: How much time does the home base need to take action? What distance is between scout and home base? This gives you a rough limit on the asteroid's speed. As example: assuming home base needs at least 1 day to react (once the the signal is received) and the scout is 1 light-day away - the asteroid must not be faster then 50% of c, otherwise the scout's signal will not arrive at home base the required 1 day ahead of the asteroid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**At 0.9c, the asteroid would be glowing brightly from impacts with hydrogen atoms in the interstellar medium, and be visible for minutes as it approaches.**

The interstellar medium has a varying density, somewhere around 1 hydrogen atom per cubic centimeter. We'll take the density to be 1.674 * 10^-22 kg/m^3. We want to calculate how much kinetic energy is being deposited onto the asteroid from impacts with these hydrogen atoms. This is (density of interstellar medium) * (speed of asteroid relative to the medium) * (relativistic kinetic energy per unit mass of the medium). Relativistic kinetic energy is (Lorentz factor - 1) * m * c^2. The Lorentz factor is 1/sqrt(1 - 0.9^2) = 2.3. [Some dimensional analysis](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28+%281.674+*+10%5E-22+kg%2Fm%5E3%29+*+1m%5E2+*+0.9+*+%28speed+of+light%29+%29+*+%282.3+-+1%29+*+%280.9+*+%28speed+of+light%29%29%5E2) says the asteroid at 0.9c would be receiving about 4.3 kW of power per square meter in kinetic energy from impacts with the interstellar medium. If the asteroid is in thermal equilibrium because it has been traveling for a long time, it will be radiating away the same amount of power that is hitting it.

At 0.9c, the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) says that 4274 W of radiation per square meter means the front of the asteroid is at about [250C, or 524K](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%284274+W%2Fm%5E2%29+%2F+%28stefan-boltzmann+constant%29%29%5E0.25). This is hot but not red hot, so the asteroid would be completely dark to the naked eye if you were standing on it. [Wien's displacement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#Wien%27s_displacement_law) says it would have a peak wavelength of about 5.5 micrometers, which is deep infrared.

However, any light from the glowing asteroid would be [Doppler-shifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect). It would look blue on approach and red as it receded. The relativistic longitudinal Doppler factor, sqrt((1 + 0.9)/(1 - 0.9)), is 4.36. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Doppler_effect_on_intensity), this means can just multiply the temperature in Kelvin by 4.36 to get the apparent blackbody temperature on approach. This would be about 2013C. Based on [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_heat), that means from the perspective of the scout ship it would be white hot, and visible to the human eye.

The Doppler effect also means we multiply the radiant intensity by the fourth power of the Doppler factor (which, again, is 4.36). So on approach, the asteroid would appear as if it was radiating 4.36^4 = 361 times as much energy. (And as it recedes it would appear as if it was radiating 361 times less energy).

If the asteroid has 2 km^2 of surface area facing the probe and is radiating 4274 W/m^2, this is 8.5 GW of thermal radiation. Multiply this by 361 and we get 3.07 TW.

How far away could a blackbody source radiating 3.07 TW be seen? For comparison, Alpha Centauri A is one of the brightest stars visible from Earth, and telescopes on Earth receive around [2.7 x 10^-8](https://homework.study.com/explanation/alpha-centauri-a-lies-at-a-distance-of-4-4-light-years-and-has-an-apparent-brightness-in-our-night-sky-of-2-7-x-10-8-watts-m-2-recall-that-1-light-year-9-46-x-10-15-m-a-use-the-inverse-square-law-for-light-to-calculate-the-luminosity-of-alpha-cent.html) W/m^2 from Alpha Centauri A.

We can model the radiation as spreading out in a half-sphere from the front of the asteroid, with area 2 pi r^2. To find the r for which the asteroid would have the same visibility as Alpha Centauri A, we set 2.7 x 10^-8 W/m^2 = 3.07 TW / (2 pi r^2). Solving for r gives r = 4.2 * 10^9 m, or 14.2 light-seconds. That means, for about 15 seconds on approach, the asteroid would be brighter than Alpha Centauri A. It would be very noticeable to the naked eye.

Of course, the probe certainly has telescopes capable of seeing objects 100 times dimmer than Alpha Centauri A. The human eye can see stars that dim. That means the probe would be able to watch the asteroid approach for at least a couple of minutes. It really depends on how good the telescope is. If it's 100 times more sensitive than the human eye it might have 30 minutes of warning.

Pinpointing the trajectory of the asteroid would be fairly simple, given that much time to watch it approach.

Almost as soon as the asteroid passes the probe it would go dark for two reasons. First, you'd be looking at the back of it instead of the front, and the back would be a lot cooler and glowing less, as it's the front that is impacting the interstellar medium. (Assuming it is not rotating, that is! If the asteroid is tumbling then all sides would be getting hit by the interstellar medium in turn, which means they'd all be glowing evenly. That means it would be a couple times dimmer on approach, and wouldn't dim as fast as it retreats. This would be a way to tell whether it's tumbling!). Second, the Doppler effect would be working against you on retreat, dimming the intensity by 361 instead of increasing it by 361, so it would immediately be 130321 times dimmer from that alone.

Comment: As far as reporting back: any report will travel (at best) at the speed of light, i.e. 1.0c, which is only 10% faster than the asteroid. If by "deep space" OP means something like "near Sol's heliopause," the asteroid would reach an inner planet in ~12 hours, and the report would arrive at the same planet only an hour or two earlier. This is not enough time for the planet to mobilize any kind of response, especially not if the response requires transmitting instructions to off-world people or facilities. (Sorry to follow such a meticulously calculated answer with my own very fuzzy math.)

Comment: Depending on trajectory, the asteroid's high-energy wake may also interfere with radio signals sent by the probe to home base.